# ADO/SQL Inserting into a database issues

Tags: html, sql, database, asp-classic, ado

simple question but this is causing me alot of hassle.
Im using asp to insert data into a database and the code looks right to me and my peers however it is not working! Here is my asp and my html form:

asp:

```vb
if request.form("submitbutton") <> "" then
    set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    conn.Open ="Driver={SQL Server}; Server=//private; Database=QuizDynamics;   Uid=QuizDynamics; Pwd=//private
    set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    rs.Open "Select * from Teachers", conn


    sql="INSERT INTO Teachers (firstname, password, lastname)"
    sql=sql & " VALUES "
    sql=sql & "('" & Request.Form("firstname") & "',"
    sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("password") & "',"
    sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("lastname") & "')"

    on error resume next
    conn.Execute sql,recaffected
    if err<>0 then
        Response.Write("No update permissions!")
    else
        Response.Write("<h3>" & recaffected & " record added</h3>")
    end if
    conn.close
end if

%>
```

html form:

```html
<form name="teacherReg" action="Registration.asp" method="POST">
    1. First name:<br/><input type="text" name="firstname"><br/><br/>
    2. Last name:<br/><input type="text" name="lastname"><br/><br/>
    3. Desired Username :<br/><input type="text" name="username"><br/><br/>
    4. Desired Password :<br/><input type="password" name="password"><br/>
    5. Confirm Password :<br/><input type="password" name="confirmpassword"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

(Im only inserting firstname, password and lastname at the moment for testing purposes)

Comment: You're subject to SQL injection. Even with old technology like ASP classic, you may still find some shield by using `ADODB.Command`.

Comment: There are also plenty of examples of functions you can use to sanitise your form data before you pass it to the database - eg http://codefixer.com/codesnippets/function_protect_sql_injection.asp

Comment: remove the `on error resume next` so you can see the actual error message (if any) that SQL is returning (or add `err.description` to the `response.write` string when `err <> 0`).  Also, you REALLY don't want to use that code, you're using `request.form` in the SQL string, very easy for hackers to hack your whole database. Better make it a stored procedure and add values as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Issue #1.

You don't have control "submitbutton".
Change from

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submitbutton">
```

I also suggest you to check request method:

```
If (Request.ServerVariables ("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST") Then 
         ..... bla bla bla .....
```

Comment: I changed the submit button to have the designated name and modified the request method. Still no luck, nothing is getting inserted into the teachers table. Can you think of what else could be the problem?

Comment: may be problem with connection string.
try something like (depending on version of SQL Server) 

Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=XXX\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Username;Password=SecretPassword;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Data Source=XXX\SQLEXPRESS;Packet Size=4096;

Comment: I doubt its that as I had a previous version of this system with the connection string given and it was working. Anything else you can think of? sorry about my persistence.

Comment: maybe some other part of your code, which are not listed there. 

I did test run of your code on my side and everything was fine. NT2003 Web edition 32bit, IIS6, SQL2005 Express.

In form I enter following data "1", "2", "3", "4"........

Do you have Visual Studio ? (Express edition not enough)

put command "STOP" in your ASP script and Visual Studio will open your page for debugging.... I hope this will help you to find problem.

Comment: Additional information about ASP script debugging:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818448/how-can-i-set-breakpoints-in-classic-asp-iis7-vs2010

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/252895

Comment: Could it be perhaps with the paramaters of the database im setting to insert into? is SQL case sensitive with such things as field names etc?

Comment: no, field names in MS SQL not case sensitive.

try to run this code for now:

    sql="INSERT INTO Teachers (firstname, password, lastname)"
    sql=sql & " VALUES ("1","2","3")

does it works well and adding one new record?

Answer (score 1):

There's an idiom for this in Hungarian: choosing between two chairs, you've ended up on the floor. :)

You've got code that's loading an entire table (all umpteen rows and however many columns - we're talking about possibly an enormous amount of data) into a recordset, but then you never do anything with it. Then you've got an Execute statement, to which you're appending a "recaffected" variable which, as far as I can tell, does not have a value. Thus, you're telling the Execute statement to apply the changes to zero records. Then, you close the connection, but you never close the recordset.

If you want to do this insert via opening a recordset (not the recommended method, but sometimes it's easier, especially if you're inserting data into dozens of columns), you'd do something like:

```vbs
If Request.Form("submitbutton") <> "" Then
    firstname = Request.Form("firstname")
    lastname = Request.Form("lastname")
    password = Request.Form("password")
    '- add code here to validate firstname, lastname, password
    Set conn = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=//private;Database=QuizDynamics;Uid=QuizDynamics;Pwd=//private"
    Set rs = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
    sql = "SELECT TOP 0 * FROM Teachers"
    rs.Open SQL,Conn
    rs.AddNew
        rs("firstname") = firstname
        rs("lastname")  = lastname
        rs("password")  = password
    rs.Update
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    conn.close
    Set conn = Nothing
End If
```

(Notice that there's a  TOP 0 on the recordset - you don't need to load any rows if all you're doing is adding a new row. You could also do something like `"SELECT * FROM Teachers WHERE 1 = 2"`.)

If you want to do this via an Execute statement, you don't need a recordset at all. Also, if you're gonna tell the Execute how many rows to apply the changes to, make sure you tell it a correct number, but it's better to simply not tell it anything.

```vbs
If Request.Form("submitbutton") <> "" Then
    firstname = Request.Form("firstname")
    lastname = Request.Form("lastname")
    password = Request.Form("password")
    '- add code here to validate firstname, lastname, password
    Set conn = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=//private;Database=QuizDynamics;Uid=QuizDynamics;Pwd=//private"
    sql = "INSERT INTO Teachers (firstname, password, lastname) VALUES "
    sql = sql & "('" & firstname & "','" & password & "','" & lastname & "')"
    conn.Execute sql
    conn.close
    Set conn = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: Note that checking for the request method doesn't hurt, but 99% of the time, it's totally unnecessary: you're the one who's writing both the form and the code to handle it, so you know whether the form is using POST or GET. Or if the handler could get data from multiple forms (with multiple request types), just check for both. `firstname = Request.Querystring("fn") : If firstname = "" Then firstname = Request.Form("firstname")`

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you and your peers need to re-evaluate the fundamentals of programming. This code is possibly the most confusing thing I have ever seen.

It is calling this:

```
  rs.Open "Select * from Teachers", conn
```

And I have no idea why.
Is it trying to...

1. Verify if someone has valid DB Connection credentials before allowing them to write to the DB?
2. Loop through it and insert the values submitted in your form for ALL teachers in your loop?

The logic here is not clear at all, and either way, is missing some things.

---

Additionally, there are Several issues with the code, if not all of it:

1. Use `Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD")` to check if a form is posted, like Zam suggests. Everything has its use, so it should be used when it can.
2. Always do server side validation on your forms **(especially for password/confirm password forms!)**.  Javascript can be disabled on the browser if you are doing solely client-side validation, which means your form will have no validation if submitted without javascript.
3. Again, it's hard to see what your trying to do with that recordset statement, but never loop through a recordset to do an insert in asp unless you really have to. Instead do one SQL statement for this. It will be **much** faster.  You can see an example here at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)
4. If you are trying to authenticate the DB connection string/password, then you should first do that part, then move into the part where you write to your DB. Using `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` should be used sparingly, you never know when there should be an error that you should be seeing.
5. You have no validation against SQL Injection. This vulnerability could compromise your entire database, very easily. You can find more information why and how to prevent it at this link on [Microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) 
   , but in most cases for SQL server, you want to make sure all `'` (single quotes) are escaped, by doubling them `''`, validate all numbers (id's) with `IsNumeric()`, etc.  before you send them to SQL server.  In other words, use `Replace(sData,"'","''")` on the values being submitted in your sql statement's. Never inject table names, etc, only values into your SQL statement.
6. Never use `Adodb.Recordset` to execute an Insert/Delete/Update statement. Use [`Adodb.Command`](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_command.asp). Again, that's what it's for.

---

That practically sums it up for me, maybe I missed something.  But there can be many reasons why your code isn't working, it would just help if you could make yourself a bit clearer why you are calling that `Recordset` object up top, and I can provide more assistance.